# How this is evaluated in PHP

Tags: php

While reading some questions on PHP. I read one question with it's answer as follows :

What will be the output of the code below and why?

```
$x = 5;
echo $x;
echo "<br />";
echo $x+++$x++;
echo "<br />";
echo $x;
echo "<br />";
echo $x---$x--;
echo "<br />";
echo $x;

Answer →
5
11
7
1
5
```

Here I am confused with $x+++ & $x--- & how its work & how exactly the expression $x+++$x++ evaluated. Can anybody please explain me about this. And also why just "echo $x+++" doesn't works & gives error.

Comment: What is the wrong?

Comment: @Frayne : Nothing wrong. I just want to know how php evaluating the "$x+++$x++"

Comment: Check out my answer to see what actually happen, and let me know if any confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey lets see:

Now `$x = 7`

if we start with this line : `echo $x---$x--;`

so whats happen???

```
($x--) - ($x--) =>  7 - 6 = 1
```

First `$x--` does not effect on the first value but the value of `$x` will be one less, if we did `$x--` in the second one then we get a less value of that variable and that is `6`, so now the firs value is `7` and second value is `6`, and because if the second value less, so the value of second portion will be less one which will effect on the next line: `echo $x`. So the last value is `5`.

**Analysis on Your Data:**

```
$x = 5;
echo $x;         // 5, Nothing changed.
echo "<br />";   
echo $x+++$x++;  // 5 + 6 = 11, increment of $x two times.
echo "<br />";
echo $x;         // 7, cause last increment.
echo "<br />";
echo $x---$x--;  // 7 - 6 = 1, decrements two times.
echo "<br />";
echo $x;         // 5, cause last decrements.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $x+++$x++;
```

this works as

```
echo ($x++)+($x++);
```

and `echo $x+++;` is a syntax error; increment you can do by `x++` not by `x+++`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `++` is an increment operator. The operator `+++` does not exist.

However, in your syntax, the code is actually reading as follows:

```
$x = 5;
echo $x;
echo "<br />";
echo ($x++) + ($x++); // 6 + 7 (increment $x by 1, makes it 6, then again to make it 7)
echo "<br />";
echo $x; // $x is 7 here
echo "<br />";
echo ($x--) - ($x--); // 6 - 5 (decrement $x by 1, makes it 6, then again makes it 5
echo "<br />";
echo $x; // $x is 5
```

This is working as expected though it seems you want to do $x+2 instead of $x++;

Answer (score 1):

this is concept of pre/post  increment/decrement. that menas first if we go with post increment menas `($x++)` what happen in this first it execute the expression which apply on that variable then it increment value by one for that variable like this below example.

```
 <?php
    $x = 5;
    echo $x++;
    echo "<br />";
    echo $x;
    ?>
```

**OUTPUT**

5

6

And second is pre increment in which what happen first it increment value for variable then execute expression which apply on that variable like below example.

```
<?php
    $x = 5;
    echo $x+++$x;
    echo "<br />";
    echo $x;
    ?>
```

**OUTPUT**

11

6

here in pre increment what happen first it adds `(+1)`in `$x` Then execute value for expression. same way pre/post decrement works[More about increment/decrement](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php)

i hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

echo $x+++$x++;
in this the equations become like ($x)+(++$x)++;
where $x=5 and as per pre increment ++$x become 6 just because post increment took effect after statement so 5+6=11 in next step
echo "
";
echo $x; // 11
//and then $x =7 because of post increment
echo "
";
echo $x---$x--;
here the same thing like above
($x)-(--$x)--
(7)-(6)--
if you're echoing $x then it must be it's initial value which was 5

Answer (score -1):

```
$x = 5;
echo $x;
echo "<br />";
echo $x+++$x++;
echo "<br />";
echo $x;
echo "<br />";
echo $x---$x--;
echo "<br />";
echo $x;
```

> Result: echo $x; = 5 echo ($x++)+($x++); = 5 + 6 = 11 echo $x; = 7 
>   //befor used increment operator echo $x---$x--; = 7 - 6 = 1 //cause of
>   decrement operator echo $x; = 5 //last decrement

Comment: This doesn'T answer the question at all

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.